# Installing package failed when trying to run to application to Meego

Tags: qt, qml, meego, meego-harmattan

I'm trying to run a Hamattan Application on a Meego Device, but everytime I try to run it into the Meego device: 
:-1: error: Installing package failed.

always appears. But sometimes when I check my phone the application is there and it's running.

In Settings->Applications->Manage Applications it says there:
Test2
Installation Failed

Please Help me. Thank you very much!

Compile Output:

```
Running build steps for project test2...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "C:\qtsdk\madde\bin\make.exe" -w
make: Entering directory `/c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2'
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
make: Leaving directory `/c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2'
The process "C:\qtsdk\madde\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
Creating package file ...
Package Creation: Running command 'c:/qtsdk/madde/bin/mad dpkg-buildpackage -nc -uc -us'.
dpkg-buildpackage: set CFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CPPFLAGS to default value: 
dpkg-buildpackage: set LDFLAGS to default value: 
dpkg-buildpackage: set FFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CXXFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: source package test2
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.0.1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by unknown <>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture armel
which: pgp: unknown command
 debian/rules build
make: Nothing to be done for `build'.
 debian/rules binary
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_clean -k 
dh_installdirs
# Add here commands to install the package into debian/test2.
/usr/bin/make INSTALL_ROOT="/c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2"/debian/test2 install
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2'
install -m 644 -p c:/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/test2.desktop /c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/
install -m 644 -p c:/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/test2.png /c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/
install -m 755 -p "test2" "/c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/opt/test2/bin/test2"
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/bcue/Qt/test2'
sed 's:^Icon=.*:Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/test2.png:' /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop > /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop.sed || echo -n
mv /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop.sed /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop || echo -n
sed 's:Exec=.*:Exec=/opt/test2/bin/test2:' /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop > /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop.sed || echo -n
mv /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop.sed /C/Users/bcue/Qt/test2/debian/test2/usr/share/applications/test2.desktop || echo -n
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_installchangelogs 
dh_installdocs
dh_installexamples
dh_installman
dh_link
dh_strip
dh_compress
dh_fixperms
dh_installdeb
dh_shlibdeps
dh_gencontrol
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: dependency on libgcc_s.so.1 could be avoided if "debian/test2/opt/test2/bin/test2" were not uselessly linked against it (they use none of its symbols).
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: dependency on libmdeclarativecache.so.0 could be avoided if "debian/test2/opt/test2/bin/test2" were not uselessly linked against it (they use none of its symbols).
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: dependency on libpthread.so.0 could be avoided if "debian/test2/opt/test2/bin/test2" were not uselessly linked against it (they use none of its symbols).
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: unknown substitution variable ${misc:Depends}
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
a - debian-binary
a - control.tar.gz
a - data.tar.gz
dpkg-buildpackage: binary only upload (no source included)
Use of uninitialized value in undef operator at /madbin/dpkg-buildpackage line 369.
 dpkg-genchanges -b -u.. >../test2_0.0.1_armel.changes
dpkg-genchanges: binary-only upload - not including any source code
Package created.
Installing package to sysroot ...
c:\Users\bcue\Qt\qt-components-qt-components\C;c:\qtsdk\madde\Users\bcue\Qt\test2\test2_0_0_1_armel.deb: No such file or directory
c:\qtsdk\madde\targets\harmattan-nokia-meego-api\bin\ar.exe: 
Cannot find package name (in debian control file).
Connecting to device...
Started uploading file 'C:\Users\bcue\Qt\test2\test2_0_0_1_armel.deb'.
Successfully uploaded file 'C:\Users\bcue\Qt\test2\test2_0_0_1_armel.deb'.
Installing package to device...
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 663 package 'mp-harmattan-rm680-pr':
 missing description
(Reading database ... 
29097 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace test2 0.0.1 (using .../test2_0_0_1_armel.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement test2 ...
aegis-installing test2 (from 'com.nokia.maemo')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of test2:
 test2 depends on libqt4-declarative (>= 4.7.4~git20110516); however:
  Version of libqt4-declarative on system is 4.7.3~git20110329-0maemo1+0m6.
 test2 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4.7.4~git20110516); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4.7.3~git20110329-0maemo1+0m6.
 test2 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4.7.4~git20110516); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4.7.3~git20110329-0maemo1+0m6.
dpkg: error processing test2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 test2
Deployment failed.
Error while building project test2 (target: Harmattan)
When executing build step 'Deploy to Harmattan device'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you updated your Qt Creator? (2.3.1 if I'm not wrong)
the update bring along the updated SDK for the meego harmattan,.
in that case you should also update your meego phone too  because there's some dependency for the newest library. (read the error, **dependency-problem**)

check here for the update package

http://www.developer.nokia.com/search/search.xhtml?view=ebs&hv=fn:type%3DfnType:Terminal&s=ft&tl=0&ob=best&me=false&l=20&expandDoc=false&k=N950+device+update&oldK=N950+device+update

this one problem makes me revert my QtCreator to the old one , I'm not allowed to upgrade the phone. duh